# Need a Formula to Countif a Range based on an input

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

Above is a snippet of data that I have (in Sheet1). 
My task is to count the number of times "C" is in, let's say from B to C, (the formula will be written in Sheet2 for this). I have the code for that and it works fine.

But what can I do to get the count based on a particular UserID entered in cell A1 of Sheet2. 
For ex: if `'Sheet2'!A1=3` then the count in row 3 of form B to C should be given:

`(Result = Countif('Sheet1'!"B2:B4","C"))`

Hope my explanation was understandable. I need a formula for this not macro.

I tried to get the row ID using Index Match but I am not able to combine it with CountIf.

Both `VLOOKUP` and `INDEX` `MATCH` can be used only if I want one cell value, but not multiple values in same row.

```
Result = Countif('Sheet1'!"B2:B4","C")
```

Comment: Check [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842). It allows you to use more conditions before making the count. It's exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant formula, but the following should achieve your desired result:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!B:B,"C")+COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!C:C,"C")+COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!D:D,"C")+COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!E:E,"C")+COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!F:F,"C")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to use **Names** in excel, you can define the following names:

- **Rng_Data** represents all your data in Column B to F
- **List_User** represents all your data in Column A

then use the following formula to find the desired count:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Rng_Data="C")*(List_User=Sheet2!A1))
```

Where `Sheet2!A1` is the given **User ID** in cell A1 on your second sheet. You can drag this formula down to apply to the rest.

In my following screen-shot, I used two sets of data to test the outcome. The first set is the same as yours and the User ID in Column A is unique. In the second set of data, there are duplicated User ID and the formula still finds the occurrence of C for the given User ID as highlighted.

**SUMPRODUCT** sometimes work like COUNTIFS but in a more powerful way.

You can read this article to learn more about SUMPRODUCT: [Excel SUMPRODUCT function with formula examples](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/08/24/excel-sumproduct-function-formula-examples/#conditionally-count-cells)

Cheers :)

[image: Solution]